# Find DataRow through itemArray value in DataTable c#

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, datarow

I want to get `datarow` from the DataTable based upon the `itemArray` value. DataTable `dtSchema` is filled by `GetOleDbSchemaTable()`. Every row `ItemArray` has Excel Sheet Name. I am doing it with foreach loop. Can it be done with some better way?

```
DataTable dtSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
foreach (DataTable item in set.Tables) // set is a DataSet
            {
                int i = dtSchema.Columns["TABLE_NAME"].Ordinal;
                if (item.Rows.Count <= 0)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow row in dtSchema.Rows)
                    {
                        if (row.Field<string>(i) == item.ToString()) // Finding data row
                        {
                            dtSchema.Rows.Remove(row);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Does your code work the way you expect? One thing you might do is, before the foreach over the rows, get the column index of the "TABLE_NAME" column. Then you could access the data by ordinal rather than by name

Comment: Code is working. Now I have update the code for finding ordinal of column. Check it @Flydog57

Answer (score 1):

```
 DataTable dtSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
            foreach (DataTable item in set.Tables) // set is a DataSet
            {
                if (item.Rows.Count <= 0)
                {
                    var MatchedRows = from s in dtSchema.AsEnumerable()
                                      where s.Field<string>("TABLE_NAME") == item.ToString()
                                      select s;
                    foreach (var item in MatchedRows)
                    {
                        dtSchema.Rows.Remove(item);
                        break;
                    }
                    dtSchema.AcceptChanges();
                }
            }
```

Comment: I tried this code and remove `break` from foreach loop. foreach loop for MatchedRows is giving error **Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute**. When it runs 2nd time

Comment: Dont remove the break. This for loop will run for one time only